# Angular 4 using checkboxes with data that doesn't include booleans

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

I have an api that returns data that I need to use with checkboxes. If I am writing an Angular 4 app and my data looks like the code below:

```
mydata = [{name: 'Clark Kent'}, {name 'Lois Lane'}];
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<div class="members-container">
      <mat-card *ngFor="let member of mydata" class="member-card">
        <div class="card-checkbox">
          <mat-checkbox>
            <h4>{{ member.name }}</h4>
          </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
      </mat-card>
</div>
```

In the controller, I want to use the checkboxes to select members to add to an array. If the api data returned a selected boolean it would be really easy to bind the checkbox to the array. I could manually add a selected field to the data but that extra step would slow down the data displaying on the screen. What is the best way to go about getting the checked members into my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the change event to maintain your own list of selected item.

```
<div class="members-container">
      <mat-card *ngFor="let member of mydata" class="member-card">
        <div class="card-checkbox">
          <mat-checkbox (value)="member.name" (change)="checked(option, $event)">
            <h4>{{ member.name }}</h4>
          </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
      </mat-card>
</div>
```

TS/JS

```
selectedValues = [];
function checked(option, $event) {
   if($event.checked) {
      selectedValues.push(option.value);
      //.. unselect etc to be implemented....
   }
}
```

**But:** A selected field is IMHO the more cleaner approach, and i wouldn't bother about the cost of that micro milliseconds for displaying.

**Best approach: seperate GUI-Data from API-Data**
You can create a new list of options based on the input data from your api, with just the properties needed to display aswell as a selected field. With this approach you will have the data seperated from your GUI and can use a selected field.

Get a list of your data for the GUI
TS/JS

```
myDataForGui = mydata.map(m => {name: m.name, selected: false });
```

HTML

```
<div class="members-container">
      <mat-card *ngFor="let member of myDataForGui" class="member-card">
        <div class="card-checkbox">
          <mat-checkbox (checked)="member.selected">
            <h4>{{ member.name }}</h4>
          </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
      </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change the   <mat-checkbox (checked)="member.selected">
            <h4>{{ member.name }}</h4>
          </mat-checkbox> to           <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="member.selected">
            <h4>{{ member.name }}</h4>
          </mat-checkbox> but worked otherwise!